# Serial communication between esp32 and iRobot Scooba 450

Tags: serial-port, esp32

I am looking to modify my Scooba 450 vacuum to make it remotely controlled.
So I searched and came across [this](http://www.robotreviews.com/chat/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=19110) and [this](http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/4-How-to-Send-Commands-to-Roomba/18.html).

After trying different ways, I ended up getting it to work in python, with a computer running at 57600 baud. So far, so good.
But for it to be remotely controlled, I wanted to use an ESP32, I tried a lot, but I can't communicate with the robot.
Normally, when it is charging, it returns information about its battery. So I put it on charge, and tried to read his data with the ESP32, but no information comes in.

I tried connecting it directly with a micro USB to micro USB cable, but without result.
I also of course checked that the cable is working, that data is currently being sent from the Scooba.

The program:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()){
    Serial.print((char)Serial.read());
  }
}
```

My goal would be to be able to control it from a site, but before that, I must succeed in communicating with the Scooba. I don't necessarily need to be connected to the computer to know if data is being received, because I can see if the LED on it is on.
Thanks

Comment: "*I am looking to return my Scooba 450 vacuum*" -- Huh? "Return" to the store for a refund? Is there a language translation problem here? "*with a micro USB cable which I cut out to be able to connect the 5V, GND, RX and TX*" -- A USB 2.x cable does not have any discrete RxD and/or TxD wires/signals that are compatible with UART signals. Such a connection is predestined to fail. That's why USB-to-TTL-serial (and USB-to-RS232) adapters exist.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you, indeed, it was a translation error that I had forgotten to modify.
For the cable, I didn't know it was impossible, thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

Based on the links you provided as well as reading this one (http://www.robotreviews.com/chat/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18181), access to the serial port on the Scooba 450 goes through a wifi dongle where you establish a console session through a TCP port. It is possible that you could hardwire a connection and bypass whatever the wifi adapter is doing, but I suspect the wifi adapter is using a proprietary (and not publicly documented) interface and protocol to communicate with the Scooba.

So, essentially just doe with the ESP32 exactly what you're already doing with your PC. Connect to the wireless adapter and use a serial console through it.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your response, and sorry for the long response time.
My problem is precisely that I cannot open a serial communication to the Scooba.
When I open the communication, I get nothing unlike when I do it with the computer.

Comment: @kik_1 with the ESP32, you'd need to be running a program that can establish a console session over a TCP port. You'd also need drivers that actually work for the wifi adapter. The likely easiest path is a uclinux or other linux build that can run on the ESP32 or maybe swapping to a raspberrypi. Alternatively, you could set up a virtual BT to serial adapter on your PC that bridges the wifi adapter on the vac and BT interface, then connect to that as a BT serial port from the ESP32. This option maintains your existing hardware but requires a PC as a bridge device.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I now think I have all the information I need. I will contact you if there is a problem.